# PHPExcel formula subtotal / teilergebnis - Excel2016 detected problems with content

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel, excel-2016

I export data from database with dynamical columns and rows so I use R1R1 / `$excel->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);`

Row 2 is my title including autofilter and line 1 on some columns i want a =subtotal().

I tried as `=SUBTOTAL()` and `=TEILERGEBNIS()` as well as C1R1 and Standard:

- `$excel->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(12, 1, "=SUBTOTAL(9;C(2)S:R(".$i.")S)")");`
- `$excel->setCellValue("M1", "=TEILERGEBNIS(9;M3:M".$i.")");`

Excel will ask to restore and will set "M1" to 0.
If i copy this value of an echo to M1 it does what it should an is what the formula is as i do it in Excel itself: `=TEILERGEBNIS(9;M3:M2315)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things wrong here

- Commas (`,`), not semi-colons (`;`) for function argument separators (unless you've explicitly set a different locale for the calculation engine)
- PHPExcel's calculation engine doesn't accept Column/Row addresses (like R1C1), just cell A1-style addresses
- English names for functions (unless you've explicitly set a different locale for the calculation engine)